# И.А.Крылов, Осёл и падежи

Tags: падежи

«Что́ то за зверь? какого род**у**?
Чай, он зубаст? рогов, чай, нет числа?»
Ну только и речей пошло, что про Осла.
Но чем всё кончилось? Не минуло и год**у**,
Как все узнали, кто Осел...

Разве не нужно **так**: какого род**а**? Не минуло и год**а**? И рифма сохраняется.

Или я "не в ту сторону" думаю? Или были какие-то особенности ровно два века назад? Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своим видением "населения вселенной".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут надо бы сделать экскурс в историю русского родительного падежа, он весьма и весьма сложный по тем функциям, которые несет, но мне это не под силу в рамках формата ресурса, постарайтесь просто принять как данность все эти названия ниже. Если вы имеете представление об эстонском, они не должны сильно пугать.

> Разве не нужно так: какого рода? Не минуло и года? И рифма
>   сохраняется.

Дело не в рифме. 
В современном русском языке - да, основной вариант родительного падежа - "года" и "рода", **партитивом** (типа "чаю" или "сахару") тут и не пахнет. Но дело все в том, что родительный падеж вобрал в себя не только исторические **посессив** (притяжательный родительный с привычными окончаниями -а/-я) и упомянутый партитив, но и еще много всяких падежей, функциональное наполнение которых сейчас полностью не воспринимается носителями.

О форме "(от) роду". В данном случае реализована одна из функций **аблатива** (родительного отложительного - он тоже впитал несколько функций, прежде чем растворится в посессиве) - откуда? - от роду, (из) какого роду (сравните: [от] какого "роду племени", "из лесу, дому"). Во времена Крылова, насколько понимаю, эта парадигма (сохранившаяся в чистом виде, например, в украинском) была еще актуальной и даже приоритетной. Так что выбор "роду" вполне обоснован.

Вот с "году" сложнее. То, что такая форма была актуальна, да и ныне существует, показывает известный фразеологизм "без году неделя". Но восстановить исторические причины её появления я не берусь. Возможно, это остатки **абессива** (другое название - каритив или лишительный), еще одного падежа, усвоенного современным родительным. Абессив, как и следует из его названия, по смыслу был некоей противоположностью поссесиву и использовался при обозначении нехватки или отсутствия чего-то.

Видимо, и тут проявление этой недостаточности, нехватки. (= **Не было** года). Но это совсем древняя форма, Крылов употребил "по инерции" или для стилизации под архаичную речь.

> Или были какие-то особенности ровно два века назад?

Да, конечно, они существовали и гораздо позже. О чем я и писал.

> КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО в последнем случае и почему? Для рифмы ведь можно
>   "изобразить" все, что угодно.

В современном языке из форм на -у/-ю актуальным является только **партитив** - (немного) сахару, меду, гороху, - причем с разными существительными он имеет разную степень необходимости, большинство же слов в этих случаях вполне обходятся парадигмой обычного родительного (поссесива), а остальные - как минимум допускают такую форму (немного льда, бензина, мела...). Так что окончание -а/-я почти всегда правильно.

В остальных же функциях падеж родительный на -у, сохранился только в отдельных сочетаниях (см. по тексту) и как стилизация архаичной речи. Но и тут надо быть аккуратным, далеко не все существительные м.р. имели такую форму во всех этих пропавших падежах. А неправильное употребление может вызвать смешение с внешне идентичными формами звательного (**вокатива**) -  "врачу, [исцелися сам]". Здесь "врачу" - форма звательного и её использование вместо родительного невозможно. "Немного врачу", "без врачу", "нет врачу" - было бы грубейшей ошибкой, по счастью, такое в голову никому и не придет.

***Коротко. В современном языке формы родительного на -а/-я можно считать правильными всегда,
на -у/-ю - иногда при обозначении части чего-либо, в остальных случаях
- только в некоторых устоявшихся выражениях и при стилизации под архаику.*** 
Но во времена Крылова архаичные формы использовались шире, чем сейчас, что и засвидетельствовано в басне.

Comment: *Знал бы наперед, сколько сил отнимет - не взялся бы отвечать )))). Чуть сам не запутался. Но тут коротко-то и не объяснишь, не упустив что-то существенное.*

Comment: Естественно, дело не в рифме...   Прежде чем задать вопрос на Форуме, я обычно САМА  занимаюсь "поползновением" по интернету и словарям.    Но не всегда получается найти нужное или отделить зерна от плевел.   Тогда я обращаюсь ко  ВСЕМ ВАМ за помощью или разъяснением, как к специалистам,  знатокам. Мне интересны и важны Ваши мнения. А выпить чая с кусочком сахара и попробовать меда  я в состоянии сама.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова *я обычно САМА занимаюсь "поползновением" по интернету и словарям* - и при этом не заметили, что у Крылова там ***тройная*** рифма?! Уж **"возят воду"** никак нельзя переделать под рифму с "рода" и "года". )))) Ладно, не обижайтесь. Просто не надо оправдываться, это не имеет большого значения, где вы там ползали. На вопрос я отвечаю именно как он задан. И непонятно, что рифма у Вас упомянута для красного словца. Плюс еще Niemand что-то там про рифму невразумительное говорил...А вы ему поддакнули.

Comment: Ух, разнесли в пух и прах!..  Да, не обратила внимания на тройную рифму, завлеклась;  но суть-то вопроса от этого не меняется.  А к Вам  "относится" только "Естественно, дело не в рифме...", остальная часть - "Niemand"у...  P.S. Кому-то  - летать на грамматических крыльях,  а кому-то  - "поползновляться",  к сожалению.

Answer (score 1):

Доводилось ли вам когда-нибудь "выпить ча**ю**", "попробовать мёд**у**"? Сколько вам кусочков сахар**у**? Знаете выражение "какого род**у**-племени"? Именно "роду", не "рода". А потом уж и году — для рифмы.

Comment: Да, конечно: и чая-чаю, и мёда-мёду, и сахара-сахару.  Я видела эти полемики на Форуме...   И  "рода (роду) - племени" интересовалась. Но так и не утвердилась, КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО в последнем случае и почему?  Для рифмы ведь можно "изобразить" все, что угодно.